# Product Based Inventory Implementation

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm working on a small inventory database project on Access 2016.

I have a problem implementing a **Product** table and a **ProductUnit** table where the following business rules are true:

1. One, two, or many products may be put in a special package to form a new product.
2. Each special package may be composed of a single product or another special-package product which itself may contain many products.

My implementation of the tables is the following:

**Product**

```
| ProductID | ProductName  | ... |
|     1     |      A       | ... |  
|     2     |    A(2set)   | ... |  
|     3     |      B       | ... |  
|     4     | A(2set) + B  | ... |  
|     5     |      C       | ... |
```

**ProductUnit**

```
| ProductID | ProductUnitID | Qty |              
|    2      |       1       |  2  |  
|    4      |       2       |  1  |  
|    4      |       3       |  1  |
```

The `ProductUnitID` is the product or special product that makes up a specific `ProductID`.
Recall that a product may be composed of many products. Therefore, there may be multiple `ProductUnitID`'s for each `ProductID` in the **`ProductUnit`** table.

Now, let's say that I have a **Sample** table where I keep a record of my products in stock.

**Sample**

```
| ID |ProductID | Qty |   
|  1 |    5     |  3  |   
|  2 |    4     |  1  |   
|  3 |    1     |  1  |
```

How would I generate a query to count my inventory products assuming that I want products such as `ProductID = 2, ProductName = A(2set)` to be count as two products of `ProductID = 1, ProductName = A`?
The same would apply for `ProductID = 4, ProductName = A(2set) + B` where I would have one `A(2set)` product and one `B` product and the one `A(2set)` product will have two `A` products.

Additional Notes: *You may disregard the following*
I'm thinking of recursive queries(if there is such a thing) that would just keep breaking each special product into products until each product is just a single product. A single product does not appear in the **ProductUnit** table.
However, I highly doubt this is possible.